# Wrong featured questions number on front page (in the tab name)

Tags: bug, interesting-page, homepage

I just went over to Stack Overflow and it struck me as odd to see that there were 0 featured questions.

I browsed over to the Featured tab and obviously there were questions (387). Also the number was showing up correctly. I browsed to the other tabs and it also showed that there were 0 featured questions, except on the Hot tab.

I went back to the Featured tab and it showed up with 0 questions (just in the tab name, the page did actually show questions). After a refresh of the page, the number jumped back to 387.

I tried to find a way to replicate the number not showing on the Featured tab as well, but can not find a good way to do so. It just seems to happen from time to time, but all other tabs have a persistent state (Hot tab shows correct number of questions, all others show 0)

On the Questions page this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Here's a screen of how it was showing up to me 
[image]

I also took this one when I was on the Featured tab and it was not showing the correct number. The second line was after a page refresh.
[image]

---

Edit:

Went back to the front page and the issue seems to be resolved. 
Is it a bug that has a really particular way of being triggered, was it not a bug and I was missing something or did it get fixed while I was typing ?

Comment: I'm actually experiencing this just now too.

Comment: after @Cupcake's comment I check my page and it seems that only the "Hot" tab is affected (for me at least)

Comment: I am just experiencing the same, although I do not get a correct number even when browsing the tab. Still works for specific tags. StackOverflow team: Eventual consistency!?

Comment: Once again tested it and yes, it's happening again ...